# Traducir el chiste en "so no one is chained inside at all hours!" en su contexto

Tags: traducción, gramática

Tenemos una tienda que está abierta 4 horas al día. Al mismo tiempo, queremos que sea conveniente para todos los clientes. Entonces, si una persona hace un pedido en nuestro sitio de web, puede elegir una hora fuera del horario normal para visitar la tienda (como una cita, appointment).

Ya sabemos que muchos clientes no entienden esta filosofía. Siempre preguntan, en este caso, "¿por qué no estás abierto 24/7?" Porque no sería justo para los empleados mantener a alguien dentro 24/7, aunque nadie planea entrar, por ejemplo a las 03:00 (¡y tampoco tendríamos los recursos para hacerlo!).

Entonces, para que todos nos entiendan, lo explicamos como un chiste. En inglés, decimos:

> Schedule: Monday 1-5pm...
>
> Also, you can pick a different time (24/7) to come to the store or you can choose to get delivery if you order online first (with a minimum 1 hour's notice). Basically, we want to be convenient for you & fair to our staff (so no one is chained inside at all hours!).

Ya lo probamos, ¡y con esa explicación todo el mundo lo entiende! Ahora tengo que traducirlo al español y no estoy seguro si el chiste ligero... traduce bien? (como no soy latino, no sé si existen connotaciones en lo que traduje)

> Horario: Lunes 13:00-17:00
>
> También puede elegir otra hora de visitarnos (24/7 cuandoquieras) o puede elegir de recibir una entrega cuando haga una pedida por nuestro sítio de web por lo menos 1 hora antes que quieras venir o quieras recibir la entrega. Básicamente, queremos ser conveniente para usted y justo para nuestro empleados (para que no haya nadie cerrado por llave adentro todo el día!).

¿Qué os parece?

Para clarificar: cuando hagas un pedido por internet, tienes DOS opciones (¡elige una!):

1. indicar una hora 24/7 fuera del horario normal para visitarnos en nuestra tienda, o
2. indicar una hora 24/7 (durante el horario normal o afuera) para recibir una entrega (o sea si quieras recibir una entrega, por supuesto sería 24/7)

Comment: I'm glad the new approach is helping, but I don't see the joke.  Is it the part about being chained inside at all hours? // I'm pretty new to this site, so I'm not certain, but I suspect your question might be more likely to stay open if you ask for help translating one specific expression.

Comment: Agree with @aparente001 but also why don't just say that you work 24/7 but only by appointment?. That would be quite simple.

Comment: I do not propose as an answer because I'm not sure of using a neutral Spanish, but I think you should say: _Básicamente, queremos ser convenientes para usted y justos con nuestro empleados (¡para que no haya nadie encerrado con llave adentro todo el día!)_ Stop avoiding cultural problems, specify that you are making a joke, for example with a happy face :).

Comment: Hi, James. There are a few issues with the text but fixing them would be proofreading, which is out of the scope of the site. Some of them include switching between *tú* and *usted*, not picking the right preposition (hora *para* visitarnos), or using the wrong gender (*una pedida*, "a marriage proposal", instead of *un pedido*, "an order"). If you want to know more about them, you can always ask a separate question. Checking one sentence (such as the last one) is accepted, but not so checking a whole text. Welcome to Spanish.SE and I hope to see you around!

Comment: "puede elegir **de** recibir una entrega". Ese "de" sobra y podrias decir tambien "recibir **la** entrega" (aunque "una" es correcto)

Comment: hi - sorry the intent is to check the last sentence, but the rest and everything else is included for context. what i struggle with is that contemporary companies in america have a very... light hearted tone in all their communications, and i'm not sure if this is appropriate to translate or how it might be done, apologies if this seemed too out of scope!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a little ambiguity with "is chained": if you are in chains, or if I chain you, in both cases someone could say "you are chained".

I would take the "put someone in chains" meaning and translate:

> para que no nos haga falta dejar a nadie encadenado al mostrador todo el día

Translating very literally back to English:

> So we don't need to leave anybody chained to the counter all day.

There are two changes: *chained to the counter* instead of just *inside* and *we leave him/her chained* instead of *he is chained*... but I think these changes help keep the humorous tone and make the Spanish rendition much more natural.

Answer (score 4):

Yo habría traducido "chained" como `encadenado`

> para que no haya nadie **encadenado** adentro todo el día!

pero mi elección habría sido usar "esclavizado", pero reconozco que puede ser un poco más controvertida (y no tienes una traducción literal del texto en inglés...)

> para que no haya nadie **esclavizado** dentro todo el día!

En lugar de "dentro" o "adentro" también podrías usar "en la tienda". No es una traducción literal pero creo que mantiene el sentido mejor.

> para que no haya nadie **encadenado** en la tienda todo el día!
>
> para que no haya nadie **esclavizado** en la tienda todo el día!

Comment: I would prefer "atado" but I never know when my vocabulary is Mexico-specific.  Example: "Lo siento, no puedo acompañarte hoy, estoy aquí atada a la estufa."  I think of the Mafalda strip where Mafalda dreams she is flying, and asks her mother to join her, but her mother can't because she's chained to her washing machine, ironing board, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes to make it easier to read.

> Horario: Lunes 13:00-17:00
>
> También puede elegir otra hora**rio** **para** visitarnos (24/7 **todo el dia**) o puede elegir <strike>**de**</strike> recibir una entrega cuando haga un <strike>**a**</strike> pedid**o** por nuestro sítio de web por lo menos **con una hora de anticipacion** que quieras venir o quieras recibir la entrega. Básicamente, queremos ser conveniente para usted y justo para nuestro empleados (para que no haya nadie **en**cerrado **con** llave <strike>**adentro**</strike> todo el día!).

I would say in Spanish this isn't funny, and using the "Usted" form gives a pretty formal tone.